# Show/hide text field depending on select option

Tags: javascript

I'm new with JavaScript and need your advice. The idea is to show/hide text field depending on select option. I have a working code, but I believe it could be more readable and better. What have I missed?

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function showHide(){
        var selectedValue =document.getElementById("choice_criteria_id").value;
        var src_addr = document.getElementById("id_src_addr");
        var dst_addr = document.getElementById("id_dst_addr");
        var port = document.getElementById("id_port");
        var port_range = document.getElementById("id_port_range");

        if (selectedValue == "source_ip"){
            src_addr.style.display = "inline";
            dst_addr.style.display = "none";
            port.style.display = "none";
            port_range.style.display = "none";


        } else if (selectedValue == "dest_ip"){
            dst_addr.style.display = "inline";
            src_addr.style.display = "none";
            port.style.display = "none";
            port_range.style.display = "none";


        } else if (selectedValue == "port"){
            port.style.display = "inline";
            src_addr.style.display = "none";
            dst_addr.style.display = "none";
            port_range.style.display = "none";

        } else if (selectedValue == "port_range"){
            port_range.style.display = "inline";
            src_addr.style.display = "none";
            dst_addr.style.display = "none";
            port.style.display = "none";
        }
}

-->
</script>
```

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Syntax :

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

Reformated code :

```
function showHide(){
    var selectedValue =document.getElementById("choice_criteria_id").value;
    document.getElementById("id_src_addr").style.display = (selectedValue == "source_ip") ? "inline" : "none";
    document.getElementById("id_dst_addr").style.display = (selectedValue == "dest_ip") ? "inline" : "none";
    document.getElementById("id_port").style.display = (selectedValue == "port") ? "inline" : "none";
    document.getElementById("id_port_range").style.display = (selectedValue == "port_range") ? "inline" : "none";
}
```

## [Example in CodePen](http://codepen.io/bugyt/pen/RaVgbY)

Answer (score 0):

Use custom "map" object on the following scheme: `{<element_id> : <dependent_value>}`.
 You can easily extend such object in case if there would be much more elements:

```
function showHide(){
    var map = {"id_src_addr":"source_ip", "id_dst_addr":"dest_ip", "id_port":"port", "id_port_range":"port_range"}, 
        selectedValue = document.getElementById("choice_criteria_id").value;

    Object.keys(map).forEach(function(id){
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = (selectedValue === map[id]) ? "inline" : "none";
    });
}
```

That's all ... )